# TestFlight app availability for internal testers

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm fairly new to iOS dev (coming from an android background). There are some things about the beta process in the Apple ecosystem that are are confusing me.

We are using Testflight to distribute our app to test users, right now just internal ones.

I uploaded a new version of the app, it showed up in iTunes Connect and I clicked the toggle to make that version available in TestFlight. It warned me that the old one would be unavailable now.

So... Now iTunes Connect says Active by the new version. I have confirmed that I am on the internal users list, but I can't download it using TestFlight (doesn't show up). Is there another action I need to take? Does it take a certain amount of time before it's available?

Comment: You might need to resend an invitation to internal testers to receive a new email link to download the new version.

Comment: Interesting... Where / how do I resend invitations. I don't see any options in the iTunes Connect interface.

Comment: The way it should work is you submit a new build of your application to the app store, then once it is finished processing, in your iTunes Connect account under the "Prerelease" tab, when the "Internal" and "External" columns say "Inactive", you then toggle the "TestFlight Beta Testing" switch to active (thereby moving previous releases to an inactive state). This should send an email to your internal testers saying there is an update available with a link to download the latest build within the email. If that doesn't work then you may have a bigger issue.

Comment: Alternative: I've used [fabric.io](https://get.fabric.io/) for internal distribution. It's incredibly easy to setup and distribute builds.

Comment: Sometimes when it doesn't send out the new version, I just toggle the switch on & off again. That typically works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug and happens every time I sent a new build to TestFlight.

**The workaround**

In iTunes Connect > Prerelease, Switch "TestFlight Beta Testing" off, then on again.

You will get a instant TestFlight app push notification in your iOS device, saying the new build is available.